# How should one call a variable which values can be summed?

Tags: continuous-data

Some continuous variables like **Precipitation** have values that can be summed. But others like **Temperature** do not. Adding two temperatures together simply does not make sense. Do these variables whose values can be summed have an adjective like **summable** or **additive**?

To better appreciate the difference between summable and non-summable variables, simply look at a Combination Chart (aka Bar Line Graph) used to display Precipitation and Temperature on the same chart. Precipitation is shown with solid bars, because it is summable, hence could be stacked. Temperatures are shown with a solid line, because they are not; hence do not need to be stacked (and could not).

The issue is not limited to temperatures by the way. And it's important, because of all the quantities defined for the measure of physical phenomenons, temperature is pretty unique. It is one of the very few quantities for which unit conversion cannot be done with a simple ratio. Instead, it requires a ratio *and* an offset. But other non-summable continuous variables can be found, especially when dealing with percentages. Some percentages are summable, while others are not. And some have their total sum capped at 100%, while others do not, especially when dealing with percentages used to measure variations of another numerical variable.

In that respect, angles are similar to percentages. In some cases, they can be summed. In others, they cannot. And when summed, their total sum might be capped to a certain level like 90 degrees, 180, or 360, or not have any cap at all. For example, a measure of rotation is not capped. But a measure of slope is capped at 360 degrees.

Therefore, it is important to realize that the summable nature of a continuous variable is not a simple factor of its unit. Instead, it is a factor of its unit in a particular context. And I must suspect that the analysis of summable variables should be different from the analysis of non-summable variables. Furthermore, the way they should be graphed are clearly different, as indicated earlier.

**Note:** the fact that a variable cannot be summed does not mean that it cannot be averaged. Indeed, an average should not be viewed as a sum followed by a division. Instead, it should be viewed as an atomic aggregation, which could be computed in many other ways. For example, Euclidian geometry can be used to compute an average between two values with a compass and a ruler, without having to compute their sums.

Comment: If adding temperatures makes no sense, then wouldn't *averaging* them be nonsensical too?

Comment: No, averaging them makes sense. An average should not be viewed as an addition followed by a division, it should be viewed as an atomic aggregation.

Comment: Would you also view addition of *absolute* temperatures as nonsensical?

Comment: Yes, because the reference for a temperature does not matter. You could add or substract temperature variations, but not temperatures themselves.

Comment: Thanks. I'm still trying to understand: would you consider  *angles* to be additive?

Comment: Yes, but not always. In that respect, angles look a bit like percentages. See my updates to the post for that.

Comment: You can add temperatures.  Temperature is the energy per unit volume.  If you have 1L of gas at 400°K and another 1L of gas at 500°K and you compress them into 1L, that gas will have temperature 900°K.

Comment: That is quite right. You can add temperatures, **sometimes**, much like you can add angles or percentages sometimes. But some other times, you cannot. Sometimes, it's a matter of the unit being used, and sometimes it's a matter of the context. For example, no matter what the unit in use, you cannot add the temperatures observed in two different cities, or in the same place at two different times.

Comment: See the thread http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/154463/what-is-the-terminology-for-data-aggregated-via-summed-totals-versus-data-aggreg for the terminology intensive and extensive.

Comment: Pedantically: Note that the units of absolute temperature are strictly kelvin K, not $^\circ$K. (Presumably when units were cleaned up in the middle 20th century it seemed that $^\circ$C and $^\circ$F were too entrenched to be modified.)

Comment: The fact that precipitation is always a sum or integral over  a time period (minute, hour, day, month, year, whatever) whereas temperature is in principle defined at any instant is important to your leading example.

Comment: Nick, would you mind adding an answer with a link to the question covering intensive/extensive? This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: I have to say that the implication of the previous thread is that this question is a duplicate.