# Model to quantify 'enabling' properties of variable

Tags: modeling, scatterplot

From a large-scale patent analysis, I have some results which can be shown in a graphic but I would like to capture them in a model somehow, to be able to quantify a fit.

The scatterplot below (in my perception) shows that up until a certain optimum, increase region diversity *enables* high radicality. Due to a huge amount of data points close to the x axis, I am unable to capture this in regression (linear or polynomial) as r^2 values are below 0.01.

[image: Scatter plot of region diversity versus radicality]

If take the average radicality over each region, a (linear) regression is possible yet I still feel it is not the most appropriate model to fit to the data: 
[image]

Based on these images, would there be a statistic/model/measure/method to capture the *enabling* capacity of *region diversity* on *radicality*?

I am sorry to say I lack experience and knowledge with statistics so apologies for my probable abuse of terminology.

Any help is highly appreciated!

[Edit]
My variables Patent Radicality and Region Diversity are derived measures:

- All patents have 1 or more technology class assigned, based on the co-  occurrence of these classes, relative distances between the classes were calculated.
- The patent radicality is the average distance between the classes assigned to it.
- The region diversity is the (Rao-Stirling) diversity of technology classes occurring in it, accounting for variety, balance and disparity.

My hypothesis is that increased region diversity should foster the radical innovation potential of that region.

I have about 5 million patents and two region levels (TL2 and TL3 as defined by the OECD) with about 300 and 2000 regions with sufficient data respectively. Both region levels yield similar results.

Comment: Can you say more about your situation & your data? What are your variables? Are these counts?

Comment: I added some additional information about my variables. I could (and in fact am) write a full thesis about this, but that will not fit on the page. If you lack any specific information pleas let me know, I'll add more details.

Comment: Looks like your "radicality" score has to be non-negative and has some very high values (>700,000) even though average radicality is only about 100. You thus might try using the log of the radicality (or the log of (1+radicality, or something similar, if you have some radicality values of 0) for your analyses.

Comment: It also would help for those trying to provide an answer to know how many patents and how many regions are involved. Hard to tell from the posted plots.

Comment: @EdM Thanks, I tried the log but this unfortunately does not yield much improvements. The [scatterplot](http://imgur.com/MPJFowh) is not very insightful. There is too much data do make anything of that.

Comment: Also, probably regions will be of different size (population count?) and a linear regression will not take that into account. Maybe an glm with log link? see my answer here:  http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/142338/goodness-of-fit-and-which-model-to-choose-linear-regression-or-poisson/142353#142353

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen, I read your answer, which is very insightful, however while it is true that  my regions are of different size( in population, surface area, and number of patents), all my variates are intensive (or at least I think so). The radicality is an average of scores while the regional knowledge diversity is calculated with a diversity-measure which controls for size (Rao-Stirling). Then I attempted to use a log-link function, but so far binomial, gaussian and gamma glm's return AIC values between 3400 and Inf, which intuitively seem quite high. Could you suggest a log-link function?