# R: linear regression with log transformed poisson like outcome

Tags: regression, logistic, poisson-distribution, linear

I'm trying to fit a linear regression on a Poisson like outcome (lots of 0's and 1's and other integers) and currently trying to create `log(y)`. However, R will return a list of numbers with lots of `-Inf` (log(0) = -inf).

I'm wondering how would make this model work by transforming the outcome variable (i.e. how other Poisson outcome linear regression models were fit)?

Please don't tell me that I should use a Poisson regression since I am. I'm trying to fit different models on the data and finding out which model performs the best.

Comment: I think that you're a little bit confused and flustered.  I recommend taking some time away from your project to catch your breath.  Once you get back, look up the poisson distribution -- it is defined on all non-negative integers.  If you have 0/1 data, its binomial, rather than poisson.  Consider reformulating your question to contain enough information for someone who knows nothing about your context to possibly help you.

Comment: Are you getting at a glm with a poisson distribution but an identity link?

Comment: @generic_user I just said there are lots of 0's and 1's but also there are other numbers and I know how the distribution looks like. Just don't know how to log transform the outcome variable.

Comment: @MatthewDrury One of the models is glm with poisson + log link but I didn't try the identity link, what is that for?

Comment: It's an uncommon model, and I'm not sure if it's really *for* anything.  I'm just trying to clarify what it is you're after, since you rejected classical poisson regression with a log link.

Comment: A moment's thought reveals why it is uncommon... it clearly violates positivity of poisson samples.

Comment: @MatthewDrury I didn't reject that, I'm fitting that model as well, log transformed linear regression is just another possibilities. I'm trying to study the fit of different models on this type of data.

Comment: 1. Poisson regression does NOT mean "take Poisson data and transform it and then fit linear regression".  2. If your data can only be 0 or 1, that's suggesting a Bernoulli model, not a Poisson one.

Comment: @Glen_b I didn't say the data is only 0 or 1, I just said there are lots of 0 and 1's but also large integers.....

Comment: In your original post it wasn't clear whether there was anything other than 0 or 1, which is why I said "*If*..." in my second point there; thanks for clarifying.

Comment: have a look at this:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/142338/goodness-of-fit-and-which-model-to-choose-linear-regression-or-poisson/142353#142353