# Can I use a Poisson model for data with a linear fit but Poisson distribution?

Tags: regression, distributions, heteroscedasticity, poisson-regression

Say I have a multivariate model which I expect to have linear fit but with a relative (not absolute) error term:

$ y = \beta X + \epsilon y$

and for which the distributions of the $X$s and $y$ are all approximately exponential.

Is it appropriate to model this data with a Poisson regression?  Or if not, what are my alternatives?  Use a linear regression but weight each data point by $1/y$?

**UPDATE**

The dependent variable is total traffic flow at various points on a network.  The independents are predicted traffic flow from different submodels (e.g. home-business, business-business, short range traffic, long range traffic etc).  So I literally expect the independent to be a weighted sum of the dependent variables, but the distributions are exponential, and error terms higher for higher flows.

Comment: A logarithmic distribution is a particular discrete distribution (e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_distribution). Do you mean lognormal?

Comment: Oops my bad.  I meant exponential.  Corrected

Comment: I guess you can, but do you want to? See my answer here:  http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/142338/goodness-of-fit-and-which-model-to-choose-linear-regression-or-poisson/142353#142353

Comment: I'm not managing to see the relevance of that answer to this problem.  Have updated my question above with details on the data set.

Comment: Question now seems contradictory. Title says Poisson, text says exponential. Do you mean exponential strict sense, or exponential family wide sense?

Comment: In a broad sense.  I have not formally tested the distributions.  Most roads carry little traffic but a few roads carry a lot.  Viewing a histogram, the distribution looks approximately exponential (if the mode is anywhere other than the minimum value it's hard to see it) but logically it's probably more Poisson like (the mode will not be at zero).