# Expected value and model expression for Zero Inflated Negative Binomial

Tags: biostatistics, negative-binomial-distribution, zero-inflation

I've been working around **Zero Inflated models**. The data that I have, however, shows overdispersion so I am using a **Zero Infalted Negative Binomial** to model counts considering exposure.

The end goal that I am trying to reach is simply to show **the expected value of children who consume a specific medication, considering their exposure to treatment**.

Here's what I have so far:

- The model, itself, should consist of two components: a zero component (logit): $P(y=j)=\pi + (1-\pi)f_{Count}(0) if j=0$
  and the actual count component (negative binomial in this case): $(1-\pi)f_{Count}(j), if j>0$
- Assuming that $\pi$ represents the probability of a 0 occuring.

So the model equation would simply require the replacement of $f_{Count}$ with the point mass function of the Negative Binomial. But in that case, the exposure is not accounted for.

For this, GLM seems to be an appropriate alternative. But I am having trouble writing the model and the expected value of it.
I've read that in $Y \sim NegativeBinomial$, $E[Y] = (1-\pi)\mu$ where $\mu$ is the mean of the density of $f_{Count}$.

So should my link function be $log((1-\pi)\mu)$? If so, how do I proceed to, still, obtain the expected value of my data, given the fact that the model that I defined is defined by branches?

(I hope I got my point across. I am sorry if the terms are statistically incorrect, I tried my best.)

Comment: The way you framed the zero-inflated model isn't quite correct. A negative binomial model can give zero counts on its own. The zero-_inflation_ model posits a separate process that leads to _more_ 0 counts than you would expect just from negative binomial. In the example [here](https://stats.oarc.ucla.edu/r/dae/zinb/), some of those who went fishing might have caught 0 fish (negative binomial), but some people didn't even try to fish and thus added additional 0 values (zero-inflated) to the observations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The log-likelihood for a [zero-inflated negative-binomial model](https://stats.oarc.ucla.edu/r/dae/zinb/) can be written as:

$$\mathcal{L} = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll} \sum_{i=1}^{n} \left[ ln(p_{i}) + (1 – p_i)\left(\frac{1}{1 + \alpha\mu_{i}}\right)^{\frac{1}{\alpha}} \right] &\mbox{if } y_{i} = 0 \\
\sum_{i=1}^{n} \left[ ln(p_{i}) + ln\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{\alpha} + y_i\right) – ln\Gamma(y_i + 1) – ln\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{\alpha}\right) + \left(\frac{1}{\alpha}\right)ln\left(\frac{1}{1 + \alpha\mu_{i}}\right) + y_iln\left(1 – \frac{1}{1 + \alpha\mu_{i}}\right) \right] &\mbox{if } y_{i} > 0 \end{array} \right. $$

where $y_i$ is the observed count, $p_i$ is the probability from the logistic zero-inflation part of the model, $\alpha$ is the dispersion parameter for the negative-binomial model, and $\mu_i$ is the mean conditional on covariate values for the negative-binomial model. The $\mu_i$ are typically modeled with a log link; see [this page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/200603/28500) among others. Predictors for the logistic and negative-binomial parts of the model can differ.

Comment: The examples you provided were very helpful. But it still didn't help me grasp how to write the model equation in terms of GLM with the exposure (offset).

Comment: @Leonor handling a continuous offset depends on the GLM link function. With a log link you include a term `offset(log(exposure))` in the negative binomial (NB) portion of the model. See [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/307383/28500), for example. If you use the method in the UCLA web page I linked, you don't need to use $(1-\pi)\mu$ in your NB model specification; the combined model iteratively estimates $\pi$ from the zero-inflation part and takes that into account for the NB part during the expectation-maximization (EM) process.

Comment: the R code for ZINB models includes two components. 
The first is the actual NB component (which includes `(Intercept)` and `Log(theta)` ) and the second is the zero (logit) component (only (`Intercept)` as I didn't specify any covariates). I am correct?
So for the expect value for my ZINB model I should only consider the first block? 

And it would be E(Y) = `exp((Intercept) + Log(theta) )`?

Comment: @Leonor I get confused by different parameterizations of negative binomials. The [UCLA OARC web page](https://stats.oarc.ucla.edu/r/dae/zinb/) is what you should trust on this. Also note that the [`emmeans` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=emmeans) supports [`zeroinfl` models](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emmeans/vignettes/models.html), which can relieve you from trying to do such calculations yourself and minimize the chance of inadvertent errors.

Comment: To write the parameterization I was guiding myself on the references on the `pscl` package (What I mentioned in the question). But still, very confusing for me as well.
That package finally gave me what I was hoping for! Thank you so much.