# Probability Distribution of Several Count models

Tags: generalized-linear-model, modeling, poisson-distribution, poisson-regression

I know how to plot and fit a count model of a Poisson distribution of a particular random variable. However, I am interested in several count models, e.g. one for each day of the week. Each day has a unique Poisson fit since the waiting times for each day are different. Is there a way to combine or describe my data with a single probability model that is conditional on the day of the way of the week? Rather than keep track of 7 simpler Poisson distributions.

Answer (score 0):

If you have one count for each day, independence between daily counts, and for $Y_t$ distributed poisson with a parameter $\mu_{\text{weekday}(t)}$ we can simply use poisson regression, which is a generalized linear model and can be fit in R as follows, with some simulated data:

```
set.seed(1001)
mu <- c(10, 20, 15, 14, 14, 5, 5)
names(mu) <- paste(c("sun", "mon", "tues", "wednes", "thurs", "fri", "satur"), "day", sep="")
n <- 52 # simulating data for 52 weeks
Y <- rpois(7*n, rep(mu, n))
x <- rep(names(mu), n)

simdata <- data.frame(x=factor(x, levels=names(mu)), Y=Y)  
simmod <- glm(Y ~ 0+x,  family=poisson(), data=simdata)
```

Then we can look at the results:

```
simmod

Call:  glm(formula = Y ~ 0 + x, family = poisson(), data = simdata)

Coefficients:
   xsunday     xmonday    xtuesday  xwednesday   xthursday     xfriday  
     2.310       3.036       2.703       2.682       2.645       1.613  
 xsaturday  
     1.586  

Degrees of Freedom: 364 Total (i.e. Null);  357 Residual
Null Deviance:      15100 
Residual Deviance: 361.4    AIC: 1890
```

finally we can compare the exponentiated coefficients with the specified poisson means (mu):

```
cbind(exp(coef(simmod)), mu)
                     mu
xsunday    10.076923 10
xmonday    20.826923 20
xtuesday   14.923077 15
xwednesday 14.615385 14
xthursday  14.076923 14
xfriday     5.019231  5
xsaturday   4.884615  5
```

In this case, we have just fitted separate means for each weekday, in a roundabout way. Let us do it directly:

```
 with(simdata, tapply(Y, x, FUN=mean))
   sunday    monday   tuesday wednesday  thursday    friday  saturday 
10.076923 20.826923 14.923077 14.615385 14.076923  5.019231  4.884615
```

So in this simple case we can do without the poisson regression formulation, but if you have additional covariates it will be handy. For more details on poisson  regression see [Goodness of fit and which model to choose linear regression or Poisson](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/142338/goodness-of-fit-and-which-model-to-choose-linear-regression-or-poisson/142353#142353)