# Looking at trend in count data

Tags: stata, count-data, test-for-trend

I have a clinic dataset with count data collected on a monthly basis from January 2013 - May 2018. There are 20+ variables. Almost all of them are "number of patients who accepted xyz treatment" in [month, year]. I have 600+ observations for the count variables and for all of them, the variance is much higher than the mean. Some of my variables are zero-inflated. Counts range from about 10/month - 1500/month.

I want to look at the number of clients who accepted xyz treatment by month from 2013 - 2018. I will do this individually for each treatment of interest. I want to test for 1) presence of trend, 2) direction of trend, and 3) magnitude of trend for all of my count variables.

I have access to Stata. What test should I use? I know how to run a poisson regression and negative binomial with count outcomes and categorical variables, but here I'm not using categorical variables so I don't know what to do. As you can probably tell, I'm a relative newbie so simple explanations are appreciated.

Comment: Look at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/321352/probability-distribution-of-several-count-models/329085#329085  you can include time with a spline term, or use a gam model (generalized additive model)

Comment: Hi, thank you. I've never used R so I'm having trouble understanding your response to the linked question. I see that you're running a poisson GLM and getting individual means for each of your time points (days), but I'm not sure how I'd be able to apply this in a way that allows me to test for trend.

Comment: I'm looking for a way to get results similar to what I would get if I ran a Cochran Armitage or Somers' D trend test

Comment: You can include time with a spline, and test if the spline term is significant. In that case there is a trend. If you can post or link some of your data, we can try some examples.