# Poisson vs Gaussian GLM: which to use?

Tags: regression, normal-distribution, generalized-linear-model, poisson-distribution, simulation

I'm going to provide a simulated case. However, the question is of a general nature (see end of the post).
Let's suppose we have some data generated in this way:

```
set.seed(123)
n <- 10000
x <- rpois(n, 2)
x2 <- rpois(n, 2)
dat <- data.frame("Dependent"= x + rpois(n, 1), "Independent"= x)
newDat <- data.frame("Independent" = x2, "Dependent"= x2 + rpois(n, 1))
```

If we were seeing this data for the first time, we would do some EDA and conclude that a closely approximating distribution could be a Poisson:

```
hist(dat$Dependent, main = "Histogram of response", xlab = "Dependent")
```

[image]

Hence, we fit a glm with Poisson process and check the fit and Pearson residuals:

```
plot(dat$Dependent, fitted(glmPoisson), main="Fitted vs real values", xlab="Real values", ylab = "Fitted")
abline(0,1, col="red")
plot(fitted(glmPoisson), residuals(glmPoisson, type = "pearson"), main="Fitted vs Pearson residuals", ylab="Pearson residuals", xlab = "Fitted")
```

From these simple plots, we clearly see that the fit is awful and residuals are clearly showing a pattern. Also, it is not able to model unseen data by the same process:

[image]

[image]
[image]

However, if we run the same analysis assuming an underlying Gaussian process, all these problems disappear and the fit/predictive power is excellent:

```
glmGaussian <- glm(Dependent ~ Independent, data = dat, family = gaussian)
summary(glmGaussian)

plot(dat$Dependent, fitted(glmGaussian), main="Fitted vs real values", xlab="Real values", ylab = "Fitted")
abline(0,1, col="red")
plot(fitted(glmGaussian), residuals(glmGaussian, type = "pearson"), main="Fitted vs Pearson residuals", ylab="Pearson residuals", xlab = "Fitted")

plot(newDat$Independent, predict(glmGaussian, type = "response", newdata = newDat), main = "New actual values vs predictions", xlab = "New values", ylab = "Predictions")
abline(0,1, col="red")
```

Hence:

1. Why, even if the underlying process is Poisson, the model is better when Gaussian?
2. In general, how can one decide *a-priori* the functional process, given that even in this simulated case we would have got the model completely wrong?

Comment: You haven't indicated how you performed the original fit.  Most likely it used a default *log* link rather than the linear link you used to generate the data.  It's wonderful how clearly your results demonstrate the model you used is the wrong one!

Comment: What matters is not the marginal distribution of your dependent variable (shown in your first histogram) but its conditional distribution given your independent variable $x$.  This conditional distribution is not Poisson but a shifted Poisson distribution with a constant variance and mean depending linearly on $x$.  Since the variance is constant, ordinary linear regression will be appropriate and robust given a sufficient sample size.

Comment: @whuber Gotcha! Good point. I did not think about that. I exactly used a _log-link_ when fitting the Poisson

Comment: See also:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/142338/goodness-of-fit-and-which-model-to-choose-linear-regression-or-poisson/142353#142353