# What would be best, using turnout levels or rates as the dependent variables?

Tags: regression, difference-in-difference

I'm looking at the effect of a specific registration requirement on turnout and have been trying to decide what form the dependent variable should take. My two main options are turnout levels (i.e. absolute values), whilst controlling for the size of the eligible population, and turnout rates (i.e. turnout levels/eligible population numbers).

Running my main specification with the two gives very different results, one being significant and the other producing insignificant results. Interpretation-wise, I am interested in how the requirement impacted turnout so I feel like turnout levels provide a more natural interpretation for this, however, all existing literature I've seen uses turnout rates, so I'm wondering if there's something I'm missing.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome. Why the difference-in-difference tag?

Comment: Also, is this [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/421283/is-there-a-difference-between-controlling-for-population-size-directly-vs-putti) helpful?