# Does the inclusion of a model offset convert predictor variables from counts to rates?

Tags: logistic, generalized-linear-model, poisson-regression, weights, offset

Does the inclusion of a model offset in Poisson or logistic regression convert predictor variables from counts to rates? Or does it only convert response variables from counts to rates?

I understand that offset variables are used in Poisson or logistic regression to account for differences in sampling intensity/exposure at each observation. The inclusion of an offset variable in Poisson or logistic regression allows you to model rates instead of counts. I understand the conversion from count to rate is done by including the units of observation as a predictor variable with a fixed coefficient/slope of 1.

A hypothetical situation:
To model the prevalence of virus_1 in a population of animals, I would build a model like below, where my response variable is the count of animals positive to virus_1 at each observation, and my offset, which converts this count to a rate/prevalence, would be log(total_number_animal_sampled). However, how would I include the prevalence of a second virus as a predictor variable in this model? If I was to include `count_virus_2_positive` as a predictor variable would this count also be converted to a rate/prevalence because of the inclusion of the model offset?

Note that the below model also includes predictor variables that are not influenced by sampling intensity/exposure at each observation, for example the abundance of animals at site at each observation.

```r
glmmTMB(count_virus_1_positive ~ offset(log(number_animals_sampled)) + 
    count_virus_2_positive + count_virus_3_positive + site_abundance, 
    data = data, family = binomial)
```

Comment: If you use "offset" with the meaning of "coefficient restraint to be 1", there's a problem with binary outcomes: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/438859/does-the-inclusion-of-a-model-offset-convert-predictor-variables-from-counts-to

Comment: If instead you use it in the sense how: "controlling for the number of trials", then here it is an example: https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/1739/conjugateprior

Answer (score -1):

The variables (response and predictors) are what they are, the use of an `offset` does not change the variables. What it changes is the interpretation of the results.

So in your example, the inclusion of predictor `count_virus_2_positive` will be as a count, not as a rate.

For discussion, see [Goodness of fit and which model to choose linear regression or Poisson](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/142338/goodness-of-fit-and-which-model-to-choose-linear-regression-or-poisson/142353#142353)