# Can dropping an insignificant factor from a model make the model worse?

Tags: statistical-significance, feature-selection, aic

I constructed a negative binomial model for examining the relationship of 1 count variable="carid_den" on another "juv_cneb_den" (with an offset="Area_towed"), along with a factor of location ="Zone".

A summary command on my full model indicates all levels of the factor are statistically insignificant (>0.05). Upon dropping this factor, however, I get a slightly higher AIC value which I think means the factor somehow made the model better. Why would the AIC value drop if the factor wasn't important? Aren't lower AIC values an indication of a better model? Is there an intuitive explanation?

My data:

```
    > head(df)
           Zone TOTAL juv_cneb_count Area_towed
    1   Whipray     2              0   383.9854
    2      West    38              0   382.2256
    3 Crocodile    25              0   408.3697
    4    Rankin     2              0   422.1000
    5    Rankin     3              0   165.5196
    6      West     6              1   266.7000


> summary(nb_full)

Call:
glm.nb(formula = juv_cneb_count ~ TOTAL + Zone + offset(log(Area_towed)), 
    data = dat, init.theta = 0.2371440904, link = log)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-1.3378  -0.7787  -0.6540   0.0000   4.0603  

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)  
(Intercept) -3.930e+01  1.575e+06   0.000   1.0000  
TOTAL        1.946e-03  9.294e-04   2.094   0.0363 *
ZoneRankin   3.220e+01  1.575e+06   0.000   1.0000  
ZoneWest     3.282e+01  1.575e+06   0.000   1.0000  
ZoneWhipray  3.119e+01  1.575e+06   0.000   1.0000  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for Negative Binomial(0.2371) family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 278.96  on 449  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 241.60  on 445  degrees of freedom
AIC: 751.89

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 1


              Theta:  0.2371 
          Std. Err.:  0.0407 

 2 x log-likelihood:  -739.8900


> summary(base)

Call:
glm.nb(formula = juv_cneb_count ~ TOTAL + offset(log(Area_towed)), 
    data = dat, init.theta = 0.1965321662, link = log)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-1.4967  -0.6980  -0.6810  -0.5667   4.1964  

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept) -6.776742   0.135157 -50.140  < 2e-16 ***
TOTAL        0.003362   0.000984   3.416 0.000634 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for Negative Binomial(0.1965) family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 252.73  on 449  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 246.63  on 448  degrees of freedom
AIC: 775.16

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 1


              Theta:  0.1965 
          Std. Err.:  0.0329 

 2 x log-likelihood:  -769.1590
```

Comment: What does TOTAL mean?

Comment: It's the sum count of another species (a prey species to "juv_cneb_count").

Comment: This is an indirect comment about your model. If I understand the design correctly, you counted two species, juv_cneb and prey (carid?), in each area. The offset accounts for the fact that a bigger area has more organisms. But the offset "applies" to the count response only, not the count predictor. Here is a related [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/438859/237901).

Comment: That's actually a good point. Yes, the offset is supposed to be applied to both the response and predictor.

Comment: Each species should actually be density (counts/area surveyed), but since the neg. binomial model only uses counts, I thought the offset would account for that.

Comment: I don't think so and neither does the answer to that other question. Maybe figuring this out will help with some of the model fitting issues?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135317/discussion-between-nate-and-dipetkov).

Comment: This is not what is happening here, but as a comment for future visitors. It could happen that a truly insignificant factor yields a better model because makes convergence easier, for example, allowing regions between local minima.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In this case you are relying on the wrong test to decide that Zone is not significant. Note that the coefficients of the Zone effect are large (>30) with huge standard errors. This happens when the likelihood keeps monotonically increasing as the estimate goes to infinity. In such cases the Wald test that gives you the z and p-values is useless. What is happening, I think, is that the Crocodile zone has 0 events, so the relative risk of the other zones compared to it is infinite.

If you were to do a likelihood ratio test for Zone as a covariate, you would see that it is significant (in fact, you pretty much did it by dropping the effect and looking at the likelihood again, you just did not compute the p-value), so you would not want to drop it.

Comment: Excellent point. I suspect that any other choice of reference value for Zone would have made things much clearer.

Comment: Ya, you're right! Croc didn't have any events (# of fish). In cases like this, is it also possible to tell R which level should be the reference? Btw, thank you!

Comment: I was able to change the ref. level, but none of the levels are significant for some reason. One is close...(p=0.0877).

Comment: It is quite possible that there are no differences among the other levels (but at least now you can see that). The key is that the level with 0 events seems to be very different, and GLMs with a log-link will have major trouble modeling it. You just cannot rely on the p-value from the parameter estimate table for any comparison involving that level, but you can use likelihood-based tests. There are workarounds with Firth's penalty, or a quick-and-dirty solution of adding 1 (or 0.5) event to that group, but I am not sure there are "easy" solutions.

Comment: Never mind all the statistics. Do we really need a regression to tell us that there are fewer fish in a *crocodile zone*?

Comment: @JDL Crocodiles 1) eat fish 2) situate themselves to be near fish. It's not clear to me which of these two wins out before looking at the data :)

Answer (score 5):

AIC is a function of the number of parameters within your model k and its likelihood L. Formally, AIC = 2k - 2 ln(L). Since a smaller AIC is better, the term 2k serves as a penalty based on the number of parameters. Thus, AIC represents a trade-off between complexity (k) and fit (L). Imagine two models with similar likelihoods, but one model features 1000 parameters and another 2 (extreme example). The simpler model with 2 parameters is typically preferred (parsimony).

In this case, you have...

- Model 1: k = 5+1, 2 ln(L) = -739.89 => AIC1 = 12 + 739.89
- Model 2: k
  = 2+1, 2 ln(L) = -769.16 => AIC2 = 6 + 769.16

So even though you have reduced the model by 3 parameters, the likelihood or fit of your initial model was enough to offset the parameter penalty, resulting in a better AIC for the larger model.