# GLM for Mixed Additive/Multiplicative Effects in R?

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, modeling

I'm in a situation where I'm fitting a GLM to a multivariate data set and presenting the outputs to a client. However (long story ...) I have just found out that the client needs the results to take an additive/multiplicative format. In other words, the model would be structured along the lines (I think) of:

```
Predicted Value = Base Value * (1 + additive_rel_1 + additive_rel_2 + ...) * multiplicative_rel_1 * multiplicative_rel_2 * ...
```

("rel": relativity)

If just additive, no problem with GLMs. If multiplicative, no problem with GLMs (using a log link function). With a hybrid of the two, what are my modelling options? Is there some modelling framework I can use to give me what I need?

Comment: Could you give some more context? What does your variables represent? Why do you need this strange form? Look at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/142338/goodness-of-fit-and-which-model-to-choose-linear-regression-or-poisson/142353#142353, what you have can be seen as a (quasi)poisson regression with offset, log link and a **nonlinear predictor function** in place of the usual linear predictor. Such models can be estimated with the R `gnm` package, see [this list](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=R+gnm).

Comment: Just edited my post - I must have been half-asleep because the formula wasn't the one I wanted to show. The reason for needing to conform to this structure is that it's in use already to derive a price for an item using various lookup tables. I can change the numbers in the lookup tables but I can't change the lookup tables in the short term.

Comment: I still think you should have a go with `gnm`. Maybe you clarify your post even better by using mathemathical notation?

Comment: Thank you. I’ve just found https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gnm/vignettes/gnmOverview.pdf so I’ll read through that when I have a moment,