# Modeling with count data as predictors and continuous as outcome variable (Bayesian)

Tags: bayesian, count-data, hierarchical-bayesian, pymc

Disclaimer: This is a long explanation but I feel like it was needed to give a thorough description of my problem. Let me know if this question is in the wrong place.

I am relatively new to Bayesian modeling and I am trying to wrap my head around a particular regression approach using count data. I understand how to model a GLM with a count variable as the dependent, such as using Poisson [e.g.](https://docs.pymc.io/en/v3/pymc-examples/examples/generalized_linear_models/GLM-poisson-regression.html) or Negative binomial. What isn't clear to me is how to implement this in the reverse way. I have been playing with baseball data because it is something I enjoy and it is the most intuitive for me. Basically my problem is this, I want to model a player's exit velocity data based on the number of hit outcomes for several types of hits. The reason I am doing it this way is because I am assuming that each hit type has a correlation with exit velocity, which is generally true but not perfect. This is by no means a good baseball question. It just sets up the problem in the way I want to try to solve. There are two issues:

1. How do I model my priors so that I can have count distributions for the predictors with a likelihood on continuous data. I searched quite a bit and did find several solutions ([example](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/574335/can-very-large-count-outcomes-be-treated-as-continuous-variables)) like this that basically say that count data is ok to be treated continuous, but that is not what I want to do.
2. I want to make inferences for each batter. Some have many observations (total hit counts) while others have few. How can I add a hierarchical structure to infer the distribution for each batter, including those with few or many observations.

I will outline what I have done so far. By the way I am using python with `statsmodels` and `pymc` for reference.

My original pandas dataframe looks like this:
| batter | type_of_hit | exit_velocity |
| :---   | :---        | :---          |
| 1      | fly_ball    | 82.6          |
| 1      | ground_ball | 92.1          |
| ... | ... | ... |
| 10      | ground_ball    | 78.9         |
| 10      | line_drive | 94.6          |
| ... | ... | ... |
| N | hit_N | velocity_N |

I can model this by converting the hits to categorical and just regress exit_velocity on hit type and batter.

`exit_velocity ~ C(batter)*C(type_of_hit)`

With the data having so many batters and varying number of hits per batter, this is a messy approach, especially since the number of total hits can be from ~5-300 per batter.

Another approach is to group by the batters, count the number of hits per type, and compute the $\mu_{\text{exit_velocity}} \pm \sigma$ for each batter.

| batter | fly_ball | ground_ball | line_drive | mean_exit_velocity | std_exit_velocity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 13 | 2 | 3 | 81.072924 |
| 2 | 3 | 5 | 0 | 1 | 92.482074 |
| 3 | 28 | 70 | 38 | 9 | 89.839477 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

Again, I can simply perform a linear regression:

`exit_velocity ~ ground_ball + line_drive + fly_ball`.

The issue is the same that I have very widely distributed total counts across batters. To remedy this, I played with regressing each player to the mean using two approaches. The first is the way that Tom Tango does it for wOBA in "The Book":

\begin{align*}
\mu_{\text{new}} & = \frac{\mu_{total} / \sigma^2_{total} + \mu_{batter} / \sigma^2_{batter}}{1 / \sigma^2_{total} + 1 / \sigma^2_{batter}}
\end{align*}

The second way I did it was to use an Empirical Bayes approach from David Robinson's book ([his blog posts](http://varianceexplained.org/r/simulation-bayes-baseball/), method is actually in Ch. 10 of the book which is not in the posts). Basically, I modeled the counts as a Dirchlet-Multinomial. After obtaining the $\alpha$ values, simply add them to each to get an estimate of total number of hits per player that is biased toward the league prior.

```
import pymc as pm
import arviz as az

# Get data as numpy array 
hit_types = ["ground_ball","line_drive","fly_ball"]
counts = data[hit_types].to_numpy()

# Reparamerization of the Dirichlet-Multinomial
with pm.Model() as model:
    frac = pm.Dirichlet("frac", a=np.ones(len(hit_types)))
    conc = pm.Lognormal("conc", mu=1, sigma=1)
    counts = pm.DirichletMultinomial("counts", a=frac*conc,n=counts.sum(1),shape=counts.shape, observed=counts)
    trace = pm.sample(2000, chains=4, return_inferencedata=True)

    az.plot_trace(data=trace, var_names=["frac", "conc"])

    alpha = trace["posterior"]["frac"].mean(("chain","draw")).to_numpy() * trace["posterior"]["conc"].mean(("chain","draw")).to_numpy()
```

It is an interesting approach and does kind of work, but it definitely has a huge shrinkage effect overall. The reality is that the mean exit velocity across all players is not *that* widely distributed, although there are a few notable exceptions (e.g. Stanton). However, this is where I feel that a full Bayesian approach will shine, where I can estimate players with low and high number of observations while capturing the uncertainty in each player's estimate. What I can't figure it out is how to model the priors.

I was thinking something like this:

```
with pm.Model() as model:

   # Priors:
   # SEE BELOW

   # Mean and std of likelihood function
   sigma_L = pm.HalfNormal("sigma_L",sigma=10)
   mu_L = pm.Deterministic("mul_L",b0 + b1*h1 + b2*h2 + b3*h3)

   # Likelihood
   obs = pm.Normal("mu",mu=mu_L,sigma=sigma_L,observed=data["exit_velocity"].to_numpy())
```

I was thinking I could model the priors as count disributions. The variance is >> mean and there are lots of zeros so I was thinking zero inflated negative binomial.

`pm.ZeroInflatedNegativeBinomial(name, psi, mu=None, alpha=None, p=None, n=None)`

If I consider only players with a sufficient number of observations (say > 100), the zeros go away and its just negative binomial (NB).

`pm.NegativeBinomial(name, mu=None, alpha=None, p=None, n=None)`

For this, I need an expected proportion (psi; only for zero inflated), Poisson param (mu), and alpha for each hit type. It seems like I need to model them jointly so do I need to do something like the Dirichlet-Multinomial for expected proportions? I am also having a hard time figuring out if I model the data `(h1,h2,h3)` or the weights `(b0..b3)` as NB.

I would like to add a hierarchical structure over players so that given a number of counts per hit type, I can estimate an average exit velocity for both players with many and with few observations.

Like I said, I am pretty new to the Bayesian framework so I appreciate your help with this issue.