# Probit/Logit or Linear regression Model?

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model, modeling

I have data about the occurence of a data breach at certain companies for the periode 2005-2018. Now I have a question about the model I should use. I have two options:

Probit/Logit: I set the dependent variable to 1 if there have been a data breach in a certain year. For example:

Company A does not suffer a data breach in period 2005-2007 --> variable Data Breach takes value of 0 for all the years 2009-2017
Company A suffers a data breach in 2008 --> variable Data Breach takes value of 1 in 2008
Company A does not suffer a data breach in period 2009-2015 --> variable Data Breach takes value of 0 for 2009-2017
Company A suffers again a data breach in 2018 --> variable Data Breach takes value of 1 in 2018
And with this data I run a probit/logit regression.

OLS:

I count the amount of times that in the sample period every company has been victim of a data breach. So in the example above, the variable Data Breaches will take the value of 2 for Company A. And with this data I run a OLS.

Notes:

Important to know is that my independent variables are all numerical variables that take values from 0 to 100, but the value might differ each year. So, for example:

Company A does not have a Cyber Committee in place for the period 2005-2008 --> Variable Cyber Committee takes 0 for all those years.
Company A does have a Cyber Committee in place for the period 2009-2018 --> Variable Cyber Committee takes 1 for all those years.
This example is just with a independent variable that takes 0 and 1, but there are also independent variables like the amount of cyber related jobs a someone had in de past. I also want to include industry and year effects in the regression, because it might be possible that in certain years or industries there were/is a higher chance of data breaches.

intuitively, I would choose the probit/logit model, but for this model it is difficult to implement the year and industry fixed effects.

I hope that anyone can help me out.

Comment: please edit your question to add necessary information such as sample size, number of companies in sample, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I would go for a logit model, since modeling the probability of being a victim of a data break seems natural.

Alternatively, with your alternative summed response (which gives you **count data**), I would not use linear regression but **Poisson regression**, which in place of a probability models the *expected number of breaks per year* (assuming you are summing within years). For an explanation of the difference see [Goodness of fit and which model to choose linear regression or Poisson](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/142338/goodness-of-fit-and-which-model-to-choose-linear-regression-or-poisson/142353#142353)

The choice between logit or Poisson regression would mostly depend on which kind of summary you want, probabilities or expected values.

You say

> intuitively, I would choose the probit/logit model, but for this model it is difficult to implement the year and industry fixed effects.

which I do not understand. Can you explain why you think so?