# Regression of Purchase Count using Offset Term to Carry Information About Package Size/Count

Tags: poisson-regression, offset, business-intelligence

Hello:  I am interested in modelling the *purchase rate* over time (an integer number of purchases, observed daily, for a number of shoppers) for a collection of 3 different products.

The data look a bit like this:

| Person ID | Date | Product ID | Product Name | Purchase Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | Mon | X | craft beer 6pack | 0 |
| A | Mon | Y | 24ct case generic lager | 0 |
| A | Mon | Z | 750mL bottle | 1 |
| A | Tue | X | craft beer 6pack | 0 |
| A | Tue | Y | 24ct case generic lager | 2 |
| A | Tue | Z | 750mL bottle | 0 |

Because the outcome of interest is a *rate* based on a count variable that includes true zeroes, something like Poisson regression appears to be a compelling option.  However, I'm struggling to decide how to handle the fact that each product has a difference case count/volume (e.g., a 6-pack of 12oz cans is ~2129 mL of beer so I would expect this item to be purchased less frequently than a 750mL bottle, all else equal).

Some of my colleagues have suggested converting all of the products to a common measurement (e.g., mL) but this results in some non-integer values due to the introduction of a conversion factor.  In response, I considered switching to a Gaussian model but this is not ideal because the data are still very granular and bounded below by zeroes (values like {0, 1, 2} become {0, 2129.29, 4258.59}.

One option that seems compelling but I am struggling with is whether I can use the *offset* term to capture the unit information about each product (e.g., use the mL-per-purchase or its inverse as the offset term).

Has anybody ever used such a technique?  If so, how did it work?  What exactly did you use as the offset and how did you construct your model?

Comment: That should be fine (maybe a quasi-poisson would be better? but offset is used the same way). For details see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/142338/goodness-of-fit-and-which-model-to-choose-linear-regression-or-poisson/142353#142353